# Data Binding issues in "MultiSelect Comboboxes inside a ListView"

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

Please help me out,
i have to populate multiselect comboboxes insode listview.
i implemented multiselect combobox and i integrated it to Listview. but i am unable to manage databinding part.

this is my XAML Code

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Task:Task x:Key="Task"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Width="278">
    <ListView Name="XAxisAttributesList" Padding="2"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,22,0"
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Task}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllItems}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="X Axis" Width="{Binding ElementName=XAxisAttributesList, Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <control:MultiSelectComboBox x:Name="MC" Width="150" Height="30" 
                                         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Task}, Path=AllItems/ModelObject}" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                                         SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"  
                                         Text="{Binding DisplayTitle}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

### Task.cs

```
public class Task
    {
        string Name;
        static ViewModel modelObject;
        static ObservableCollection<Task> allItems;
        public Task()
        {
            Task.CreateTasks();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Task> AllItems
        {
            get { return allItems; }
            set { allItems = value; }
        }

        public Task(string Name, ViewModel _modelObject)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            modelObject = _modelObject;
        }

        public static void CreateTasks()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Task> list = new ObservableCollection<Task>();

            List<string> all = new List<string>();
            all.Add("1");
            all.Add("2");
            all.Add("3");

            List<string> selected=new List<string>();
            selected.Add("1");

            list.Add(new Task("Item1", new ViewModel(new MultiSelectDemo.Attribute(all, selected, "Item1"))));
            list.Add(new Task("Item2", new ViewModel(new MultiSelectDemo.Attribute(all, selected, "Item2"))));
            list.Add(new Task("Item3", new ViewModel(new MultiSelectDemo.Attribute(all, selected, "Item3"))));

            allItems = list;
        }

        public string Option
        {
            get { return this.Name; }
        }
        public ViewModel ModelObject
        {
            get { return modelObject; }
        }
    }
```

please
see the image here

[image]

instead of populating item 1,item 2 and item 3 it populating only item3 all the time

Comment: You're binding to `SelectedItems`, but there is no `SelectedItems` property in your Task-class?!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually two problems:
The first problem is:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Task}, Path=AllItems/ModelObject}"
```

should be `DataContext="{Bindind ModelObject}"`

The second problem is that `static ViewModel modelObject;` should not be static.